# Can we apply PCA for regression?

Tags: regression, pca

A very simple question? For a regression problem, can we use PCA? or is PCA only for classification problems?

A lot of time spent on statexchange/google on the same topic confused me further. some ppl said yes , some said since PCA only works on covariance between X values and not X and Y values it cannot be used.

Comment: Something like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_regression?

Comment: Short answer: yes. PCA is a linear change-of-basis from one set of descriptors $x_1,\cdots x_n$ to another $x_1',\cdots x_n'$.  The new set of descriptors has the feature that they have zero covariance, which might seem alarming if you expect to perform regression. In fact, any variable would regress to zero slope against any other variable in a pure first order model. But of course your models are more sophisticaed than that! You are free to choose a new response variable $y'=x_j'$ develop a model for it *specifically* involving nonlinear transformations of the remaining $\{x_k'\}$.

Comment: hmm looking at https://ncss-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/themes/ncss/pdf/Procedures/NCSS/Principal_Components_Regression.pdf and https://newonlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat508/lesson/7/7.1 and https://www.idtools.com.au/principal-component-regression-python-2/, the technique seems pretty similar to PCA on classification. it runs pca on x, and then runs a regression model on transformed x and y. what is the difference then between pca and pcr???